# Cannot use the namespace System.Net.Http .NET Framework 4.6 in Unity

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, dll

I am trying to import the `System.Net.Http` library in my C# Script in Unity.

I have installed this library from the NuGet Manager in Visual Studio 2017. It was added in the References and then I imported the **System.Net.Http.dll** file in a plugings folder in the Unity project, but Unity doesn't accept it. It shows me this error message :
"Loading script assembly "Assets/DLL/System.Net.Http.dll" failed!"

Comment: Are there any error messages? What *exactly* do you mean by "Unity doesn't accept it"? Also please specify the version of Unity and the player runtime you're using.

Comment: I am editing the quastion so you can understand me better.

Comment: So *which* version of System.Net.Http.dll did you copy into your assets folder? And which runtime are you using?

Comment: Unity3D uses Mono. I don't think you'll be able to run this except somehow wrapping it and running it as a plugin and even then it'd only maybe work for Windows.

Comment: @McAden Unity handles that for them: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptingRuntimeUpgrade.html

Comment: @Eddge Didn't think that necessarily meant you could plop a complete .Net 4.6 binary and expect it to work. I stand corrected.

Comment: What's your Unity version?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to reload the assembly, that solved to me.